# Attaching mousedown with mousemove event in javascript?

Tags: javascript, events

How can I attach the mousedown event with the mousemove event, this is better explained in a example:

```
      var mousemovemethod = function (e) {
            var oldx = 0;
            var direction = "down";
            x = this;
            x.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
                if (e.pageX < oldx) {
                    direction = "left"
                } else if (e.pageX > oldx) {
                    direction = "right"
                }
            });

            document.body.innerHTML = direction;

            oldx = e.pageX;

    }

    document.addEventListener('mousedown', mousemovemethod);
```

So what this code does is when I click down it displays `down`, so the mousedown event handler works just fine, however while pressing down I want to be able to move right or left, and obviously replace `down` with `left` or `right`.

jsFiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ft8pdup6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, except that you're forgetting to update the html after setting left or right

```
var direction = "",
oldx = 0,
mousemovemethod = function (e) {
    var oldx = 0;
    var direction = "down";
    x = this;
    x.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
        if (e.pageX < oldx) {
            direction = "left"
        } else if (e.pageX > oldx) {
            direction = "right"
        }
        //You forgot to to this
        document.body.innerHTML = direction;
    });

    document.body.innerHTML = direction;

    oldx = e.pageX;

}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1qfg8xtw/

Also you're not removing the event after releasing the button. I assume that's intended (if not, it's not hard to solve).

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this problem, thought I should post it here :

```
var oldX = 0;
var move = function(e){
    if(e.pageX < oldX){
        document.body.innerHTML = "left";
    }
    if(e.pageX > oldX){
       document.body.innerHTML = "right";
    }
     oldx = e.pageX;
}
var start = function(event){
    document.body.innerHTML = "down";
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", move, true);
};
document.addEventListener("mousedown", start, false);
```